# Syntax Error when writing a function using "this" on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, this

I wrote this function and Firebug tells me that there is a Syntax error, I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with the "this".

```
function TituloRepetido(this){
    var es=false;
    for(var i=0; i<listaPeliculas.length; i++){
        var p=listaPeliculas[i];
        if(this==p['titulo']){
            es=true;
        }
    }
    return es;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What did you mean by 'this'?

Comment: I've answered your question, but you'll need to post more code to figure out your issue.

Comment: what is this? do you know?

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, as I said I'm really new at this.. and I'm learning js and jQuery at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a reserved word in js that is similar to 'this' in c# it refers to the current function object.

just change that word with something else:

```
function TituloRepetido(title){

    for(var i=0; i<listaPeliculas.length; i++){
        var p=listaPeliculas[i];
        if(title==p['titulo']){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

current function is evaluating if title exists in lista de peliculas and returning a boolean

Comment: Although it could be made more efficient by returning early and eliminating the `es` variable.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it. I use the es variable because they don't let me make functions with different return statements.

Answer (score 4):

`this` is a reserved keyword in javascript that refers to the instance in your current scope, which also means that you can't use it as a param.

Comment: That makes sense admdrew, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `this` as a parameter.  It is a reserved word that refers to the instance of an object from within itself.  Use a different parameter name.